# switch actor behavior with akka and scala

Tags: scala, akka

What is the correct way to switch activity between actors.

for example 
actorA - send 100 messages to the actorB. 
ActorB will print it into console. After 100 messages actorB will send 100 messages to the actorA and actorA will print it. Switch actor behaviour each 100 msg.

Thansk

Comment: You can change the state of the actor using [`become`/`unbecome`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome).

Comment: You might want to check this [feature](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Become_Unbecome)

Comment: Take a look into aggregator pattern http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/aggregator.html

Comment: Consider using Akka's finite state machine (FSM)for anything more complex than an aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it (this is a very quick solution, probably not the most elegant one, suggestions for improvement are welcome). The main part is the following actor which can either send or receive messages. It changes its behaviour after sending (respectively receiving) more than `numberOfMessages` messages.

```
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object SenderReceiver {

  case class StartSending(other: ActorRef)  // see explanation below
  case object TheMessage  // dummy placeholder for actual message
  case object SendMessage // a reminder for the actor itself to send a message

  def props(numberOfMessages: Int): Props = Props(new SenderReceiver(numberOfMessages))

}

class SenderReceiver(numberOfMessages: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging {  

  import context._
  import SenderReceiver._

  // initial receive in order to determine the actor's initial role 
  def receive = {
    case StartSending(other) =>
      log.info("I'm sending first, yay!")
      sendNext(0, other)
    case TheMessage => 
      log.info("It seems, I'm receiving messages first.")
      become(receiveMessages(1))
  }

  // receive function for when actor is a receiver of messages
  def receiveMessages(messagesReceived: Int) : Receive = {
    case TheMessage => 
      log.info("Message received")
      val messagesReceivedNew = messagesReceived + 1
      if (messagesReceivedNew < numberOfMessages - 1)
        become(receiveMessages(messagesReceivedNew))
      else
        sendNext(0, sender)
  }

  // receive function for when actor is a sender of messages
  def sendMessages(messagesSent: Int, other: ActorRef) : Receive = {
    case SendMessage =>
      other ! TheMessage
      log.info("Message sent")
      val messagesSentNew = messagesSent + 1
      if (messagesSentNew < numberOfMessages - 1)
        sendNext(messagesSentNew, other)
      else
        become(receiveMessages(0))
  }

  def sendNext(messagesSent: Int, other: ActorRef) {
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500 milliseconds, self, SendMessage)
    become(sendMessages(messagesSent, other))
  }

}
```

Initially, the actor is in a state where it does not know yet whether it is a sender or a receiver. In this case, two things may happen:

1. Either the actor receives a message, in this case, it knows it is a receiver, and therefore `become`s a receiver.
2. In the other case, the actor needs to be explicitely told that it is a sender (in particular, it needs to know where to send to!), before it can `become` a sender.

Once the actor knows what its role is, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. It sends (or receives) a certain number of messages, and afterwards switches to the other behavior.

In order to run this code, here are some more snippets you might need. First, here's some simple auxiliary actor that sets up the whole system and stops it after a while (it gets a bit boring after ten seconds or so...)

```
object Terminator {
  case object StopThem
}

class Terminator extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import Terminator._
  import SenderReceiver.StartSending
  import context._

  val actorA = system.actorOf(SenderReceiver.props(3), "actorA")
  val actorB = system.actorOf(SenderReceiver.props(3), "actorB")

  actorB ! StartSending(actorA)

  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds, self, StopThem)

  def receive = {
    case StopThem =>
      log.info("Stopping actors now")
      system.shutdown
  }
}
```

And, for the sake of completeness, a simple `App` to start everything

```
object SenderReceiverAkka extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  val terminator = system.actorOf(Props[Terminator])

}
```